# SUM not working with timestamp calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to grab the sum of a row within my database where the timestamp is for today. The issue I'm having is that it's only grabbing the first row, not all of them. When I remove the `WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()` the `SUM()` works, with it, it fails and only returns the first value in the database. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
SELECT COUNT(bg) as totalBg, SUM(bg) AS bgSum FROM `bglogger` WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: i think timestamp is keyword so you if time stamp is your column name you just enclose it with back ticks . it will work

Comment: SELECT COUNT(bg) as totalBg, SUM(bg) AS bgSum FROM `bglogger` WHERE `timestamp` >= CURDATE()

Comment: Luckily, this site isn't governed by the random thoughts and beliefs of others.